# How do I silence mysqlcheck?

Tags: mysql, debian-squeeze

If I use for example:

```
mysqlcheck syscp --silent --auto-repair
```

I still get the note:

> syscp.panel_sessions
>   note     : The storage engine for the table doesn't support check

this is strange, cause in the manpage it sais:

> --silent, -s
>              Silent mode. Print only error messages.

It seems, --silent only suppresses OK-messages.

How can I suppress notes and warnings too, so I really get only errors?

maybe parse the output with grep?

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88694/grep-all-lines-but-one-before-the-hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a known bug for some years now, without any progress:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47547

> [23 Sep 2009 11:23] Shane Bester
>
> Description: mysqlcheck has the --silent option which is not silent
>   enough. It prints out warnings and notes still:
>
> "-s, --silent        Print only error messages."
>
> shell>./mysqlcheck test --check --silent test.t1 note     : The
>   storage engine for the table doesn't support check test.t2 warning  :
>   Found row where the auto_increment column has the value 0
>
> How to repeat: drop table if exists t2,t1; create table t1(a
>   int)engine=memory; create table t2(a int auto_increment primary
>   key)engine=myisam; insert into t2 values (1); update t2 set a=0;
>
> mysqlcheck test -uroot --check --silent
>
> Suggested fix: don't print out warnings and notes when operating in
>   silent mode.
>
> [23 Sep 2009 11:49] Valeriy Kravchuk
>
> **Thank you for the problem report. Verified just as described**.

You'll need to find another workaround, like you are stating with the grep suppression.  Is the output that bad to look at or are you wanting a way to pull the errors out and do something with them?

Answer (score 0):

We cant.It's a bug. It will print warnings and notes in silent mode also.
Please check this mysql bug. [Mysql bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47547)